# How can I start JUnit @Suite from GUI's button?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, automated-tests

How should I start JUnit @Suite from GUI's button? I created several classes with auto tests. Every class has autotests with specific functionality. Also I made suite for these tests. I want start different tests from GUI's button(using JFrame). How can I do it? (I already made GUI)

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Atp.class, Authorization.class, MainMenu.class})
public class SuiteTestClass { }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. To run the test suite from Intellij, there is the green "play" button for it.
Could you update your question and explain better what you mean with *using JFrame* ?

Comment: I want test suite to start through GUI wich I've already made using Java Swing

Comment: Did you make the gui to run the test suite? Is it the GUI that you developed the test subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-tests-run-programmatically-from-java

3.4. Running a Test Suite

it could be helpful for you.